# Finding a limit for n tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I find the limit of this function:

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$$  for any real $x$?

I tried using the sandwich theorem but couldn't reach the proper inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider the sum formation of $e^x$.